# VHDL Numeric_STD Metavalue detected

Tags: vhdl, ieee

So I'm writing some VHDL and ALL my comparisons are raising this error (where "=" is replaced by whatever operator I'm using in this comparison).

```
WARNING: NUMERIC_STD."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
```

Supposedly this is caused by either one of the values being uninitialized or the comparison being impossible but I really don't see how this could be. I've included my code below (both Temp_EA and Temp_EB are unsigned (7 downto 0)

```
  Temp_EA <= "10001000";
  Temp_EB <= "10000000";
  
  Name : process (Temp_EA, Temp_EB)
  begin
  
    if Temp_EA > Temp_EB then
    
    -- Code
    
    else
    
    -- Code
    
    end if;
    
  end process;
```

Comment: You're code isn't a [mcve], the warning can't be reproduced without simulation. Every process (including elaborated concurrent assignment statements) executes during initialization kick starting simulation. Signal assignment updates without an **after** time expression cause a delta cycle without simulation time advancing.  The updates from assignments to Temp_EA, Temp_EB don't take effect until the beginning of the next (delta) simulation cycle, meanwhile their value is the default (all 'U's) cause the warning when they are evaluated in the Name process during initialization.

Comment: Sorry for the poor question but if its badly formulated its because I don't have the knowledge to write it properly. I'm quite new to VHDL and haven't yet been taught about delta cycles yet. From what I gather this would run properly in simulation? Do I have to worry about these warnings?

Comment: There are two ways to eliminate the warnings here. Provide initial values for Temp_EA and Temp_EB in their declarations (not shown) or change where the Name process waits for events on them. A sensitivity list elaborates to a final statement, a wait statement of the form `wait on sensitivity_list;`. Here remove the sensitivity list and as the first statement of the process add `wait on Temp_EA, Temp_EB;`

Comment: Your theoretically complete and otherwise syntactically and semantically correct (there's a reason for asking for a [mcve]) design specification will run as is. It produces a warning from a function call implementing the binary operator ">". Because there would be *events* on Temp_EA and Temp_EB.  Warnings that are understood can be safely ignored. Eliminating them as a matter of policy takes a bit more care.

Comment: You've shown the warning, but not its timestamp. I'm betting that was 0 ns, before the assignments to Temp_EA/B took place. See earlier comment about initial values...